# Simple VBA routine needed for exam

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am sitting an exam in the morning which involves HTML and a small bit of VBA.
VBA isn't my stong point and Im asking for help with this particular practice question:

"Write a simple VBA subroutine to illustrate how to insert data into a range of cells"

Sounds relatively easy but the lecturer put zero notes online, 
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do with HTML?

Comment: Why, there's no way you can insert data into a range of cells without HTML.  (wink)

Answer (score 2):

will keep this somewhat abstract as it is homework and i dont wnat to gift you the answer

alt-f11 opens the vba-editor thing

maybe make a module using the appropriate button

a subroutine should look a bit like

```
Sub insertIntoCell()
    ' right code here
End Sub
```

take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139976%28v=office.10%29.aspx) documentation, you may wish to consider some form of [iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing)

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a good example or tutorial and I think a found a good one to go into VBA programming. [This](http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic2.htm) gives you some basics and a example handles with ranges. I hope it will help you go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Range("A2").Value = 1000
```

Comment: Way to stick with the spirit of the thread ...